# Interprocess synchronization using mutex in windows(win32 or C++)

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, synchronization

I want to build thread synchronization between 2 processes. basically one thread is running in a App1.exe and a second process is running in App2.exe. How do i synchronize these 2 threads in windows. can someone please share some examples or links.

Answer (score 5):

Possibilities:

- A WINAPI Mutex is an interprocess synchronization mechanism. See [Using Mutex Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for an overview.
- [`boost::mutex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.mutexes). One reason to prefer this is the provided `scoped_lock` feature that ensures a lock is released regardless of how a scope is exited (exception or multiple `return` statements).

Comment: This is it. In particular, note that Windows mutexes are cross-process (the process-local mutexes are called [critical sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Comment: Windows mutexes are cross-process only if you specify a name.  Obviously, there's rarely a reason to prefer a mutex if you're not using is cross-process and plenty of reason to prefer a critical section.

Comment: So named mutex should be used and the Name has to be shared between the process ?

Comment: @user1687824, that is correct. You should also read [Kernel object namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382954(v=vs.85).aspx).